# select exists statement return int or boolean

Tags: sql

I want to know if a exists select statement like this one

```
SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * from example WHERE exampleid=1);
```

returns a 1 or 0,or a TRUE or FALSE

Comment: Depends on what database system(s) you're using, which is why you should tag your question with the relevant one(s). In plenty of systems this statement is not syntactically valid, but given the wide variety I can't exclude the possibility that in some, it's not (and in those the type of the value may in turn vary).

Comment: @Stu it is valid in RDBMS that have a boolean datatype. E.g. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=b9709f3e6231ce208a20d870b97f2b04 or https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=b9709f3e6231ce208a20d870b97f2b04

Comment: Yes I just tested in a Fiddle that's true - in which case the answer is presumably true (not 1/0); saying that Postgres returns t / f and mysql 1/ 0 so the answer is it depends.

Answer (score 0):

The EXISTS operator *evaluates* to a Boolean value, as already mentioned in the comments. Whether that results in 1/0 or True/False (or something else), however, will depend on the particular DBMS being used.

[SQLite, for example, evaluates to **integers** 1 (True) or 0 (False)](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#exists_op).